# QGraphicsView Won't Expand

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having extreme trouble getting QWidgets to expand as needed.  This isn't the first time I've run into this problem, and last time I solved it by hacking in a large sizeHint().  This is the WRONG approach and I would really like to learn the CORRECT approach.

If anyone could help me out it would be greatly appreciated.  Here's what it looks like and the layouts I have written in code.  If necessary I can supply the code.  Please help me learn Layouts.

**Edit**: The first layout mock up actually works correctly.  I am attaching another layout mockup which causes a problem.

[image: Example Of Resizing]

---

[image: Mock Up of the Layouts]

---

[image: Breaks Expansion]

---

Code. Three classes.

MainWindow Class:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget * w = new MainCentralWidget(this);
    setCentralWidget(w);
}
```

MainCentralWidget Class:

```
MainCentralWidget::MainCentralWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    SetupLayout();
}

void MainCentralWidget::SetupLayout()
{
    QVBoxLayout * main_layout;
    QFormLayout * plugin_layout;

    //Start
    main_layout = new QVBoxLayout();

    //Setup the plugin chooser
    plugin_layout = new QFormLayout();
    QComboBox * plugins_box = new QComboBox();

    plugin_layout->addRow("Choose Plugin: ", plugins_box);

    QFrame* line = new QFrame();
    line->setFrameShape(QFrame::HLine);
    line->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Sunken);
    plugin_layout->addRow(line);

    main_layout->insertLayout(0, plugin_layout);

    main_layout->insertWidget(1, new SubWidget());

    //Finish
    setLayout(main_layout);

    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
}
```

SubWidget Class:

```
SubWidget::SubWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: yellow }");

    setMaximumSize(10000,10000);
    setMinimumSize(100,100);
    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
    SetupLayout();


    //setMaximumSize(10000,10000);
}

void SubWidget::SetupLayout()
{
    QHBoxLayout main_layout;

    main_layout.setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
    main_layout.addWidget(&m_graphics_view);
    m_graphics_view.setMaximumSize(10000,100000);

    setLayout(&main_layout);
}
```

Comment: Provided, thanks lol4to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void SubWidget::SetupLayout()
{
    QHBoxLayout main_layout;

    main_layout.setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
    main_layout.addWidget(&m_graphics_view);
    m_graphics_view.setMaximumSize(10000,100000);

    setLayout(&main_layout);
}
```

Your `main_layout` gets destroyed immediately after `SetupLayout` finished, as it goes out of scope. So, actually, your `SubWidget` has no any layout. That is why widgets are shown incorrectly.

Comment: Yep I figured that out moments ago... I am having extreme trouble separating when I can use Qt classes on the stack (see implicit sharing, eg. QPen, all of QtXML) and when to use heap objects.

Comment: @Constantin As a general rule of thumb, if it derives from `QObject` then create it on the heap, otherwise you can create it on the stack.

Comment: @Constantin, in Qt, methods that take pointers indicate that they will continue to use those objects after the methods have returned. The objects don't have to be in the heap, as long as they don't go out of scope.